# Aptitude - find new versions of packages

Tags: linux, aptitude

How do I find out if new versions of installed packages exist **without** installing them via aptitude in non-interactive mode? Is there anything comparable to the MacPorts `port outdated` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apt-get -u -s upgrade